# ruby select on multiple conditions

Tags: ruby

I have a array consists of Hashes, let's called it `student`:

```
> $students
> [
    { :name=>"John",  :last_name=>"Nutter",  :rating=>7, :well_behaved=>true },
    { :name=>"Tom",   :last_name=>"Hanks",   :rating=>8, :well_behaved=>true },
    { :name=>"Jason", :last_name=>"Willams", :rating=>9, :well_behaved=>true }
]
```

I have implement a `select` method to select by condition from `student`:

```
def select selector
  $students.select(&selector)
end

def name_selector name
  ->(student) { student[:name] == name }
end

# ... other selectors
```

`select(name_selector('Jason'))` will return students of name 'Jason', which is nice.

What I am trying to accomplish is passing multiple selector, implemented as `where` using keyword arguments:

```
def where(name: nil, last_name: nil, rating: nil, well_behaved: nil)

end
```

Expected:

`select(where(name: 'Jason', well_behaved: true))` will return students of name 'Jason' and `well_behaved` is `true`.

I am lost on how to implement this, could someone give me advices. Any advices are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it `$students` or `students`?

Comment: `$students`, it's a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def where(name: nil, last_name: nil, rating: nil, well_behaved: nil)
  ->(cd) {
    name         ? cd[:name]         == name  :        true &&
    last_name    ? cd[:last_name]    == last_name :    true &&
    rating       ? cd[:rating]       == rating :       true &&
    well_behaved ? cd[:well_behaved] == well_behaved : true
  }
end
```